# Display limit mysql php code

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, row

I don't understand how to display the first three rows (this number is an example limit) of a mysql database table with php code. I know how to use LIMIT, but in this case it seems not to work. Here is the code:

```
include("common.php");
    $link=dbConnect();

    $limit = safe($_POST['limit']);

    $i = 1;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $dbName . `scores` ORDER by `score` DESC LIMIT $limit");


         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))        
         {    
         echo  $i . "\t° \t " . $row['name'] . "\t - \t " . $row['score'] . "\n";
         $i += 1;
         }
```

This code produces an output like this: [view image](http://s28.postimg.org/7oew0vpjx/2014_07_21_164322.jpg).
So it shows all the rows of the db table and not only the first three for example...
Thanks to everyone who will help me!

Comment: What is the value of your `$_POST['limit']` ?

Comment: Please also be aware that the `mysql_*` API is deprecated. Instead you should look into PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: Thanks all...So the php code was right, the error was in Unity3d C# code where I had written "public int limit = 3;" and not "private int limit = 3". This was the error..

Comment: thanks again for the quick responses

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check two things $_POST['limit'] value and then $limit value. safe function may make it something different.

Answer (score 0):

echo the text: "SELECT * FROM $dbName . `scores` ORDER by `score` DESC LIMIT $limit"

See what output it gives is the limit / dbName what you expect it to be

If you don't see what is wrong run the query in for example phpMyAdmin sql section see what errors you get in return.